# Postman Test using switch statement for HTTP status codes

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, postman

I'm trying to create a test in Postman to return different text responses depending on the outcome of the switch statement. However, i'm not sure why it says no tests available when i click 'run' I have my Get method set up correctly as when i execute it on its own it returns e.g. 200 OK. I have the below:

```
var statMessages ;

switch (statMessages) {
  case '500':
    console.log('Internal Server Error.');
    break;
  case '200':
    console.log('200 Ok');
    break;
  case '503':
    console.log('Service unavailable.');
    break;
  case '502':
    console.log('502 bad gateway.');
    break;
  case '599':
    console.log('Network connect timeout error.');
    break;
  case '408':
    console.log('Request timedout.');
    break;
  default:
   console.log('Sorry, we are out of ' + statMessages + '.');
}
console.log("Try again?");
```

Comment: Where's the actual Postman Test? Was is `statsMessages`? You'll need to capture the status code ( `pm.response.code` ) to know what to switch too right.

Comment: I was trying to use 'statsMessages'. I'm not sure how this looks. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

[image]If I don't misunderstood your question then I think you should try like this way. Grab HTTP Status Code like on your `statMessages`

```js
var statMessages = responseCode.code; // it'll return numeric code e.g 200

switch (statMessages) {
  case 500:
    tests["Internal Server Error."] = statMessages === 500;
    break;
  case 200:
    tests["200 Ok"] = statMessages === 200;
    break;
  case 503:
    tests["Service unavailable."] = statMessages === 503;
    break;
  case 502:
    tests["502 bad gateway."] = statMessages === 502;
    break;
  case 599:
    tests["Network connect timeout error."] = statMessages === 599;
    break;
  case 408:
    tests["Request timedout."] = statMessages === 408;
    break;
  default:
    tests["Sorry, we are out of" + responseCode.code]
}
```

Comment: I tried this however it is returning '200 ok' when the actual current status is 'Server unavailable'?

Comment: Replace `responseCode.code` with `pm.response.code`

Comment: @DannyDainton You have to use the standalone version of Postman for the **pm** to be accessible. **pm** is not available on the version of postman that is with Chrome extension

Comment: As that's also be depreciated and not worked on anymore - You probably need to migrate away from that too. :)

Comment: @DannyDainton yeah you're ri8. :) thnx

Comment: Guys, updated with image of test results. Please see the Pass - 200 OK compared to the actual response returned from the server as '500 Intenal Server Error'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the reasons for using the `switch` statement here (I'm sure it's for something in your context) but if you're just testing for specific code to be returned and to see a log message, you could just have something basic like this:

```
pm.test(`Status code check - Status Code was: ${pm.response.code}`, () => {
    pm.expect(pm.response.code).to.be.oneOf([500,200,502,599,408])
})
```

[image]

If the assertion failed, the test would fail and the error will show you what status code was returned.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Danny. I tried your code snippet and it runs, however the output shows as : PASS Status code check. But doesn't tell you which code was returned

Comment: Updated my answer to show the status code in the Test's name.